# Load Legacy PrestaShop classes from deploy.php file

Tags: php, prestashop, autoload, prestashop-1.7, legacy-code

From deploy.php file in the root of my Prestashop project I call a method

```
    ModuleManagerBuilder::getInstance();
```

that in turn calls other Legacy Prestashop classes like `Configuration`
This throw an error:

`[Error] Class 'Configuration' not found`

This Legacy PS classes doesn't use namespace syntax so it is like the autoload is not aware of this old classes

The PrestaShop team worked to solve the problem only if the Legacy Class is called from classes in /src and /tests folder like explained here: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/autoload.php

How can I make deploy.php aware of this PrestaShop Legacy classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is to load `config/config.inc.php` in your file